# Why do we need to model max, min, and average temperature for infection disease

Tags: spatio-temporal

For COVID-19, I read many papers who try to find the relationship between COVID-19 and temperature. In these papers, the authors found the relationship between daily confirmed cases of COVID-19 and temperature, using maximum temperature, minimum temperature and average temperature. For me, I think that the number of the recorded confirmed cases is the same for the day. For example, if the government report that 200 people infected at 02-Feb-2020, and 215 at 02-Feb-2020 and so on.  Then what is the idea behind find the relationship between the confirmed cases for max, min, and average of that day?

If the tag is not appropriate for my question, please let me know what is the best one.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't the best place to ask such question. It is about some research questions in the area of epidemiology, while this is a Q&A site on statistics and machine learning. The question would be valid if you asked something like *"if I want to model relationship between COVID-19 cases and the temperature, how approach this problem?"*.

Comment: Covid-19 is a respiratory infection. These type of infections are very common around winter, and the period during which these diseases occur with high frequency is even called the 'respiratory season'.

Comment: The exact reasons why these infections mainly occur around winter are not exactly known. Temperature is one of the factors which is believed to influence the spread and severity of the infections in many ways.

Comment: So ***that** is why there is an interest to study whether Covid-19 follows a similar pattern as other respiratory infections and might have a lower frequency of occurrence when the temperatures are higher.*

Comment: However, **the idea** behind *"the relationship between the confirmed cases for max, min, and average of that day"* **is probably false**.


The number of confirmed cases is a very *indirect* measurement, and this makes the relationships between cases and temperature of the *same* day less strong.

Comment: For example, I can imagine that those confirmed cases are based on lab results which are only processed a few days *after* a particular person experienced complaints and went to a doctor for a test. And also that moment of getting complaints may not be the only aspect related to weather, and also the transmission could be influenced by weather, which happens many days before a person gets covid-19 and ends up as being reported.

Comment: So determining the relationship between weather and covid-19 case reports on such fine timescale is probably not gonna make sense and (since it is done a lot these days, as it is a hype) it will likely result in the "discovery" of many spurious correlations.

Comment: **However, comparisons on large time scales might make more sense.**

Comment: - For instance colder climates might have respiratory seasons that last longer (e.g. Canada with the SARS outbreak in 2002/2003, and currently with COVID-19 the Scandinavian countries and Russia) although in the case of this pandemic it might be tricky to investigate that as the longer duration of the virus may also have to do with a later start of the outbreak since the virus did not spread out everywhere at the same time, and many high density populations where the virus is likely to spread first are around the same latitude.

Comment: - Another example to study effect of temperature is the difference between the countries on the norther/southern hemisphere. Although that is also difficult to analyse. The population on the southern hemisphere is not so large and dense (roughly 10% of the entire world population) so that can be reasons why they only had small peaks (like Australia and New Zealand), late peaks (like Argentina, Brazil and South Africa). And also there are countries with hardly any data (like Tanzania or Angola).

Comment: So what is actually needed are either controlled studies on the spread of the virus (that is, laboratory studies). Or possibly data might be used, but then more details are necessary, like tracking down the exact time (or likely time) that people got sick and with who they had contact (such that it can be compared with *realistic* models, and models that can take into account temperature).

Comment: But when Australia and New Zealand are soon gonna experience a second wave during their winter, while the people in the north can carelessly enjoy summer, then this will also be a good indication that the weather will play a role. The same is true when the virus pops up again next December.

Comment: **So you are right in thinking that differences like *"200 people infected at 02-Feb-2020, and 215 at 02-Feb-2020 and so on"* are not really a significant difference.** But that is not the way that the relationship between the disease and virus should be related. (It will be done over longer timescales instead. And note that such comparisons on longer timescales *might* include data with shorter timescales, but the point of the comparison will be to compare it for a larger amount of data and not for single days)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thank you so much for your great comments. I appreciate them. Yes, I agree with you. I just surprised why these researchers study the relationship between COVID-19 and temperature for say 20 days. I strongly agreed with your 6th comment. So, I think it is not acceptable to study the association between the number of confirmed cases and the corresponding temperature of that day, as people did not infected at this day, but many articles are there!!.

Comment: @Tim Thank you so much for your comment. It is really a good advice.